# encode list of words at the character level

Tags: python, numpy

I want to implement a function that receives a list of words and returns a tensor

The idea is to create tensor per each word where each row is filled with zeros and single one that represents the letter in that position. for example the word `"abc"` will be represented by the following tensor:

```
tensor([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a combination of dictionary mapping and [`F.one_hot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.one_hot.html) which is a built-in to perform dense-to-*one-hot* conversions.

1. Construct the dictionary mapping *str* to index. We will insert an additional character `"0"` to conveniently add some padding to words that are shorter than the maximum length:

   ```
   >>> alphabet = dict(zip('0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', range(27)))
   ```
2. Find the maximum length and pad the words that are shorter:

   ```
   >>> max_length = max(len(w) for w in words)
   ```
3. Pad all words with the appropriate number of `0` characters:

   ```
   >>> padded = [w + '0'*(max_length - len(w)) for w in words]
   ['cd0', 'abc']
   ```
4. Now construct the tensor by looping over all padded words and characters:

   ```
   >>> dense = torch.tensor([[alphabet[c] for c in w] for w in padded])
   tensor([[3, 4, 0],
           [1, 2, 3]])
   ```

Finally apply [`torch.nn.functional.one_hot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.one_hot.html):

```
>>> x = F.one_hot(dense, num_classes=27)
tensor([[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

All this time we've worked with a dictionary containing `26 + 1` values, where the extra character `"0"` was to one-hot encode the pad values. We can now remove the first column corresponding to `"0"`:

```
>>> x[..., 1:]
tensor([[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```